# How to install requests, beautifulsoup4, bs4 modules

Tags: python, pip, python-3.7, python-module, kali-linux

I have updated pip and pip3 to latest version and have installed requests by sudo pip install requests and sudo pip3 install requests by this command it is showing satisfying notification but when I tried to import it gave error in python3.7.5 but accepted in python2.7.17. How do I  solve it in python3.7.5.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwtKA.jpg)

Comment: Do not link to images of text. Instead, copy and paste the text directly into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `requests` without `sudo` command. 
That should work. :)